# Tracking AJAX requests in GAnalytics

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to figure out how to track AJAX requests on my page with Google Analytics (in this case, we are loading more category results). This is the code I'm adding on my page:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXX');
</script>
```

I was led to believe that running this after the AJAX requests would do the trick:

```
ga('set', 'page', this_url);
ga('send', 'pageview', this_url);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. How would I do this? On our old setup you just do:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', this_url]);
```

...and this tracks it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figured it out. I was reading this article:

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/

...and it mentioned about the "push" function:

```
 window.dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'Pageview',
 'url': this_url
 });
```

Sure enough, adding that in and I now see the extra page view going through to Google Analytics. Hopefully this helps save someone a bit of hassle!